# Word 2007 footnotes causing blank pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

I'm working on formatting a Word document with 96 footnotes over 57 pages (a chapter from my wife's dissertation). Some of the notes are very long. After making some adjustments to the document to match the University style manual, suddenly Word seems to be choking on some of the larger footnotes.

There are now several pages in a row with none or just one line of text (not all have a footnote associated). So page 5 is normal, page 6 is blank, page 7-9 have 1 line of text on them including a short footnote on page 8, and page 11 has the start of a very long note.

Any suggestions about what's going on and how to fix it?

**Additional Information:**

After playing with the section some more I've come to the conclusion that I'm encountering a bug in Word's footnote layout calculations when handling very long footnotes (this one is over a page on its own).  When I move the reference marker to the end of the paragraph the problem suddenly goes away.  If I shorten the long footnote the problem goes away after reducing the size a bit.  If I widen the margins a bit the problem goes away.  It seems to be a certain combination of long footnotes in the middle of paragraphs that will cause the problem.  It seems to be an edge case, so hopefully not many other people will find this questions helpful.

The only solution I have found so far that is at all viable is to move the marker to the end of the paragraph.  That's not viable in all cases so I would still love to know if anyone has encountered this bug and has solutions.  I'll post mine as an answer, but I'd love to have some other options for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, move the footnote marker to the end of the paragraph.